# Parse PFQuery Predicate Pointer Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I am performing a simple `PFQuery` to fetch  a bunch of `Box` objects (class name).

My `Box` has  a pointer to a `Toy` object called `toy`.

I let my user select a bunch a toys, then the search only display the `Box` objects with those `Toy` objects.

So I end up with an `NSArray` of `PFObject`s of type `Toy`. I have an array of `objectId` strings for the objects, and I just create another array like this:

```
PFObject *obj = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"Toy" objectId:objectId];
```

Now I can query the object, I would have thought. I have tried doing a query of `Box` objects with an `NSPredicate` which looks like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"toy = %@", toyObject]];
```

My app crashes and tells me it is unable to parse that. So before adding the predicate I take the `objectId` instead and try doing that:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"toy.objectId = %@", toyObject.objectId]];
```

However, it doesn't like that format either. So how can I create an `NSPredicate` that lets me only fetch objects with a specific pointer result like explained.

Answer (score 2):

In other words just use

```
 PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fromUser = %@", user];
```

where in this example, "user" is a pointer stored in the table and we're searching for it under the "fromUser" column

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making this too hard on yourself. If I'm reading your question correctly, there is a much simpler way to do this, and you don't have to use `NSPredicate` at all:

```
NSMutableArray *toys = [NSMutableArray array];
// Figure out some way (during selection) to get the "toy" objects into the array
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Box"];
[query whereKey:@"toy" containedIn:toys];
[query findObjects... // You should know the rest here
```

And that's it! Nice and easy, should find all `Box` instances that have a `toy` that is contained in the `toys` array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I probably was over complicating, but I found the answer! While your method works, I need to use an NSPredicate, and the reason it couldn't parse the format was because I was using `stringWithFormat`, which screws up NSPredicates.

Comment: For your stated problem, you don't **need** to use `NSPredicate`. What other information makes you think you do?

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify, I was trying to keep the question as simple as possible. I don't `need` per-say but it is easier in my scenario as I need to pass it around bunch and command among other things. Thats why I said I wanted to achieve this using an `NSPredicate`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was pretty simple.

Don't use `[NSString stringWithFormat:(NSString *)]` if you are creating an `NSPredicate` format string. `NSPredicate` really doesn't like it and can often fail to parse your format.